# Java Strings and Returns

Tags: java, string, return

I'm getting a result of "ac" when I use the word ("spaces") for String s.

```
public static String boom( String s )
{
  if(s.length()>5)
  {
    return s.substring(2,4);
  }
  if(s.length()>1)
  {
    return "" + s.charAt(1) + s.charAt(s.length()-1);
  }
  return s;
}
```

I understand how the first condition is being met and the substring that results, however, why doesn't the second condition execute the next statement?  The length of the string is  greater than 1.  Is this because once the first return is executed, the program is finished?  Do I need to use arrays or something else if I'd like to have multiple returns within 1 method?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: you answered your question "once the first return is executed, the program is finished"

Comment: Functions exit when a `return` is reached. What result are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: For your own sake, as well as for those reading your code, indent it.

Comment: Use multiple checks using OR(||) operator, AND(&&) operator before `return`ing

Comment: I'd like the function to continue to check the additional conditions within that function.

Comment: @Nick But what are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: show us the method that calls boom and what it does with the returned data.

Comment: last question: there is (at most) only one value returned by a method. Yes, you can (must) use an array or some collection (List) if you need more 'results' (or have them stored somewhere else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return causes the execution of the function to stop, returning the value.

try something like...

```
public static String boom ( String s ) 
{ 
   if ( s.length ()> 5 ) { 
      s = s.substring ( 2 , 4 ); 
   }
   if ( s.length ()> 1 ) { 
      s = "" + s.charAt( 0 ) + s.charAt( s.length()- 1 );
   }
   return s; 
}
```

Comment: if the length is 5, the second if-block will change nothing (despite creating a new string instance) since the first if-block will leave just 2 characters in `s`